# There were undefined references

Tags: bibtex

I get this error when I try to run my file.
I try to put in a reference, but I only got `[?]`.
This is the main document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage % Hieronder voeg je de hoofdstukken in
\input{../tex/hoofdstuk1}
\input{../tex/hoofdstuk2}
\newpage
\section*{References}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

And this is the `.bib` file.
[image]

In the file `hoofdstuk2` I refer to a source like this: `\cite{Tsao2013558}`
I don't understand why my reference is displayed as `[?]`.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rather than posting screenshots it is much better to post the actual code (and then highight it using the `{}` symbol in the gui). This makes it much easier for people to help you because they can cut-and-paste your code, allowing them to easily edit and test it on their own system.

Comment: Did you run pdfLaTeX(F6), then BibTeX (F11) and then pdfLaTeX (F6) twice?

Comment: I did but it is stel not working.

Comment: main tex:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Hieronder voeg je de hoofdstukken in 
\input{../tex/hoofdstuk1}
\input{../tex/hoofdstuk2}
\newpage
\section*{References}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}




\end{document}

Comment: When I put in a reference with \cite{} He recognizes the sources I made in the .bib file, but still there comes [?]

Comment: If I press f11 I get this comment: I couldn't open file name `main.aux

Comment: I normally run latex + bibtex + latex + latex on the main tex file. Then, I compile my pdf to see whether the reference shows up. In most of the cases, it does

Comment: Possible helpful: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)

Comment: If the post Sam linked doesn't help you, I suggest you post also the raw text of your .bib file (at least the relevant part). And also `hoofdstuk2.tex`. Please don't  post it as a comment but edit your question. I did part of that so that you can see how it works. This will increase your chances of getting help

Comment: You have to include a `\bibliographystyle{<style>}` and you have to remove `.bib` from the name of the bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the given MWE is that it does not contain a `\bibiographystyle` thus `bibtex` stops with the error

```
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file hoofdstuk2..aux
(There was 1 error message)
```

and it does not produce a `.bbl` file.